# QLineEdit IP partial validation

Tags: qt, ip, qlineedit, qregexp

In my project I want to filter some of my data via IP input.

I also want to allow to filter by partial IP input
for example : 192.168.

I found out how to set the complete IP validation.

```
  QString oIpRange;
    QRegExpValidator *poIpValidator;

    // Client IP validation mask
    oIpRange =
            "(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";
    QRegExp oIpRegex ("^" + oIpRange
                     + "\\." + oIpRange
                     + "\\." + oIpRange
                     + "\\." + oIpRange + "$");
    poIpValidator =
            new QRegExpValidator(oIpRegex,
                                 poQtLineEdit);

    // Client IP set validator
    poQtLineEdit->setValidator( poIpValidator );
```

I connect the QLineEdit "returnPressed" signal to my filter function.

The problem is that the "returnPressed" signal only emitted when I enter the complete IP and not for partial.

Any suggestion how to fix that issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QRegExpValidator` to do that.

```
// #include <QRegExpValidator>
QString oIpRange = "(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";
QRegExp oIpRegex ("^" + oIpRange
              + "\\." + oIpRange
              + "\\." + oIpRange
              + "\\." + oIpRange + "$");
ed->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(oIpRegex));
```

Answer (score 0):

For partial validation:

```
oIpRange = "(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";
QRegExp oIpRegex ("^" + oIpRange
                 + "\\." + oIpRange
                 + "(\\." + oIpRange + ")?"
                 + "(\\." + oIpRange + ")?$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer I add a minor fix to the regular expression

```
QString oIpRange = "(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])";
QRegExp oIpRegex ("^" + oIpRange
                         + "(\\." + oIpRange + ")?"
                         + "(\\." + oIpRange + ")?"
                         + "(\\." + oIpRange + ")?$");
```

Comment: This will not compile!